# Is is possible to get user input from Power BI and transport to R for analysis and calculation?

Tags: r, powerbi

I try to create a pricing tool. I searched and found out that Power BI and R can be used together. I want to use Power BI to get user input, and transport to R scripts for analysis and calculation. I know Power BI can take R output, but am not sure if R can take input from Power BI. The tool I am trying to create is similar with mortgage quote or insurance quote. User put numbers on Power BI and R take numbers to do the analysis. Can the tool be created through Power BI + R? Thanks!

Comment: Currently there is no way to get user input in PowerBI

Comment: How about enable R script in Power BI and use R script to get user input? @msta42a